# Why does call off mean postpone?

Tags: expressions, verbs, sentence, errors, particle-shift

As a synonym of "postpone", "call off" can be used.
But, I can't understand why "call off" has a meaning of "postpone".
Please tell me its origin.

Comment: Does *call off* mean *postpone* or *cancel*? [See dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/call-something-off?q=call+off).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the question is based on an incorrect assumption (that "call off" = postpone).

Answer (score 1):

In some contexts, such as sport, the verb "call" can be used to mean "declare that something is a" - eg "call foul", meaning "To declare something as being a foul".  This probably originated from the referee literally shouting, ie "calling", "Foul!" and so "Call 'Foul!'" becomes "Call foul".

Using this meaning, to "call off" means "To declare something as being off", and "off" is a synonynm for "cancelled".  So if you were to say "We don't have enough players, I'm cancelling the game", this could be worded as "We don't have enough players, I'm calling off the game", and this could be further shortened to "I'm calling it off." or "I'm going to **call off** the game."

Comment: Please don't answer blatantly off-topic questions. Especially when you haven't actually answered why it means postpone? (Which I wouldn't expect you to, because it doesn't have that meaning.)

Comment: @curiousdannii I, for some reason, read it as "Why does "call off" mean "cancel"?" which i think is an example of how our brains often intepret reality as what we expect to see rather than what we actually see :)  I don't know why you think it's off-topic though.

Answer (score -1):

I would imagine it comes from the use when dogs were used as a security force and there was a command to get them to stop, referred to as 'calling them off' as calling the dogs off their pursuit.

Comment: But that does not mean that the pursuit is postponed!

Comment: @curiousdannii I think that's exactly what it means.

Comment: Then please present some evidence that many people use it that way.